# Wait async function to finish from console Main()

Tags: c#

How I can wait in Main until RunScrapper() function finish in my console application?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunScrapper();
    }

    static async void RunScrapper()
    {
        // Download the Chromium revision if it does not already exist
        await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);

        // Create an instance of the browser and configure launch options
        Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = false
        });

        // Create a new page and go to Bing Maps
        Page page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        await page.GoToAsync("https://www.google.es");
    }
```

If I put `await RunScrapper();` it says that Main() should be async and RunScrapper() should return a Task.

The problem is that the program runs and nothing happens because the program closes before RunScrapper() makes anything.

Comment: Did you know you can change the Main method to be async as well?

Comment: Also, don't make your `RunScrapper` use `async void`, do `async Task` instead.

Comment: Use `static async Task Main()` instead. Definitely change `RunScrapper` to `async Task RunScrapper`. Only asynchronous event handlers are meant to use `async void`. Such a method can't be awaited. Right now, your application exits without waiting for your async method to complete

Comment: Main method needed: static async Task Main(string[] args)

Answer (score 3):

You can change your Main method to be Async.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
       await DoStuffAsync();
}

public static async Task DoStuffAsync(){
       ...    
}
```